# Android RecyclerView fading edge appearing abruptly and using padding incorrectly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently converting a ListView in my Android app to use RecyclerView instead, but am having difficulty recreating the fading edge effects used by the former.

Firstly, I've set the RecyclerView to have bottom padding and use `clipToPadding="false"` to make sure the padding is only visible when you scroll to the bottom of the list, which is working. However, the fading edge does not appear along the bottom edge of the RecyclerView's visible box, instead it acts as though `clipToPadding="true"` and appears a little way up the RecyclerView.

Secondly, the fading edge does not smoothly grow/fade in when you start scrolling as it does for ListView, instead appearing suddenly at its full length and intensity as soon as you begin scrolling.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lists_overview_recycler"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="12dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:paddingBottom="48dp"/>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: i am having same problem ....when you remove padding and clippadding it suppose to work as expected